# Парсинг JSON в JAVA Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, api, jpa, spring-boot

Задача состоит в том, чтобы запарсить данные с api в виде json и записывать в бд postgresql.

json выглядит так:

```
[{
   DepId=123, 
   PoName=Название, 
   PoType=Тип, 
   Mestnost1=Городская, 
   Mestnost2=Стационарное, 
   PoStatus=1, 
   PostIndex=010000
 }]
```

Можете скинуть какие-нибудь примеры, все вроде обшарил или не правильно шарил.

Comment: Но это не JSON.

Comment: Для работы JSON в Spring смотрите [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (в Spring Boot он есть из коробки). Но в вашем примере формат больше похожий на работу метода toString() на списке объектов, а не JSON.

Comment: А, извиняюсь, да, это не json. Это я через restTemplate записал уже в List. Дальше я в тупике, как мне вытащить, к примеру, DepId и PoName?

Comment: Добавьте сам код, который у Вас получился.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте класс

```
public class DepartmentDto {
    @JsonProperty("DepId")
    private Integer depId;
    @JsonProperty("PoName")
    private String poName;
    @JsonProperty("PoType") 
    private String poType;
    @JsonProperty("Mestnost1")
    private String mestnost1;
    @JsonProperty("Mestnost2")
    private String mestnost2;
    @JsonProperty("PoStatus")
    private Integer poStatus;
    @JsonProperty("PostIndex")
    private String postIndex;

    // геттеры, сеттеры
}
```

Получайте через restTemplate коллекции экземпляров этого класса и делайте с ним, что хотите (например, перекладывайте в JPA Entity-класс и пишите в базу).